# Steam api user data: Only works for one steam id, else DOESNT WORK

Tags: php, steam-web-api

I'm really new to php and doesnt understand much with apis.. 
I wrote this code:

```
<?php
$steamkey = "xxxxxxxx"; // censored I use the right steamkey
$id_user = "76561198059606697"; // only this steam id works

$apifr = "http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUserStats/GetUserStatsForGame/v0002/?appid=730&key=".$steamkey."&steamid=".$id_user;

$data = file_get_contents($apifr); // put the contents of the file into a variable

$test = json_decode($data);

echo print_r($test->playerstats->stats[0]->value, true);
?>
```

the result is the total_kills of the player steam id:

```
49999
```

The result "49999" are the right total_kills of the player in csgo, which actually works just fine, but if I try different steamids it doesnt work anymore...

Could someone please help me and explain why or give another solution to use the steam api for csgo player stats?

Thank you all

I tried more then 10 different right steam ids, however they doesnt work... 
Some people have names instead of for example "1231943812" as a steam id, it doesnt work too, I dont know how to use the names too

Comment: You're not using `$id_user` in your code...

Comment: Sorry I edited my code to a string "ZyklopRT" to test it better instead of a variable, to check if the variable doesnt works..

Comment: I changed it back to how I have it and how it isnt working properly, Thanks.. please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use **public** steamids which means the player has to put their profile to public visibility.

Try some accounts from this list `https://steamdb.info/stats/toplevels/` which includes almost only public accounts. If you can see the profile details of these players than you should be able to get that info.

[Here](https://steamid.io/) you can convert the profile pages into steam ids.